# write in one field several email

Tags: javascript

I my HTMT page, I have a input field which receives an email address

***My html:***

```
...
<label for="email">E Mail :</label>
<input class="form-control email" type="text" type="email" required="required" th:value="${user?.mail}" name="emailChangeState" id="emailChangeState" />
...
```

***My js:***

```
..
var emailChangeState = document.getElementById('emailChangeState');
var result = validateEmail(emailChangeState.value);
..         
if (!emailChangeState.value) {
    showErrorAlert("Error", "No Valid Mail");
} else if (result != true) {
    showErrorAlert("Error", "Mail look like xxx@yyy.com");
} else {
    ..
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

I want to ensure that I can write in my fields several email

***Example:***

> yy@xx.com;tt@pp.com;zz@oo.com

but i have this js alert:

> showErrorAlert("Error", "Mail look like xxx@yyy.com");

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.split(';')` to extract emails to array and then loop through array with validator

Comment: JavaScript has an explode function?